# register_nav_menus() won't register menus

Tags: menus

Please help with menu registeration:

I have followed this guide (http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) step by step.

Added the following code to functions.php:

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array('header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ) )
  );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

But the guide says that this will make the menu appear in the Appearance -> Menus admin screen in the "Theme Locations" box as "Header Menu".

When I go to Appearance -> Menus everything is greyed out and there is no option of "Theme Locations"

Comment: Add a screenshot of `wp-admin/nav-menus.php`. And do something with your other orphaned questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to add any action to register your Nav Menu. Here are some quick steps for you to get your Wordpress Nav Menu to work...

**Register Nav Menu**

```
if (function_exists('register_nav_menu'))
{
    register_nav_menu('header_menu', 'Header Menu');
}
```

**Define and Use Nav Menu in your Theme:**
Usually we place the Menu DIV code in header.php file; so I assume yours is also in header.php file. Open that file and locate the DIV container where you wish your Wordpress NAV menu to appear. Here is a sample from one of my recent Wordpress themes for your ready reference:

```
<div class="css-nav" >

<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
    'menu_class' => 'css-menu',
    'title_li' => '<div class="l"></div>',
    'link_before' => '<span class="l">',
    'link_after' => '</span>'
) ); ?> </div>
```

Once you add this code, go to your WP Admin - Menus. Create a new Menu, if you don't have any yet. As soon as you create a menu, you should see "Theme Location" meta box to the left side of your Menu Item arranger area.

I hope this helps. :-)

Cheers,

Ruturaj.

Comment: +1 for a well-formatted, good answer from a new user. Welcome to WPSE. :)

Comment: `function_exists('register_nav_menu')` doesn't do anything useful: `nav-menu.php` is loaded before the theme’s `functions.php` (see `wp-settings.php`). `'sort_column'` and `'title_li'` are not valid arguments.

Comment: Thanks...This works! Finally! Documentation at Wordpress could use a serious update

Comment: Wow! One of the 3 menu locations appeared as soon as I put down if `(function_exists('register_nav_menu')) `, but how do I make the other two show up?  ` if (function_exists('register_nav_menu')) {`
   
    `register_nav_menus('headerMenuLocation', 'Header Menu Location');`
    `register_nav_menus('footerLocationOne', 'Footer Location One');`
    `register_nav_menus('footerLocationTwo', 'Footer Location Two'); }`